# Get related objects

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates

I have a normal user, who has some measurements, each of which can have one or more tagged results:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    born = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    ...

class Measurement(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='measurements')
    ...

class MeasurementResult(models.Model):
    measurement = models.ForeignKey(Measurement, related_name='results')
    tag = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    value = models.FloatField()
    ...
```

I would like to get all users, with all measurements, and with tags for all results, so that I can do the following:

```
{% for user in users %}
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">{{user.name}}, {{user.age}}</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">{{user.tags}}</div>
    <div class="col-md-4"><a href="{% url 'user_detail' user.id %}"> View detail</a></div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

I have here some issues, which I do not know how to solve properly:

- `user.age`: I do not have the age of the user, but the date when the user was born. How can I add an age property, derived from the born property in the database, to the users in the queryset?
- `user.tags`: this is more tricky, since the tags are to be obtained from a union (set) of all tags of all results of all measurements for the given users. I guess I need to use annotations for this, but do not know how to do it.

Currently for the age I have added a method to the `User` model:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    ...
    def age(self):
        '''Returns the age of this user'''
        if not self.born:
            return None
        today = date.today()
        return today.year - born.year - ((today.month, today.day) < (born.month, born.day))
```

Is this the correct may of adding a property to the model? By adding a method? Or is a better *Django way* of doing exactly this?

And to add the tags, I have a simple helper function which adds a property to each user:

```
def get_users_with_tags(skip_user=None):
    '''Lists all users, adding to each user the measurements results' tags'''
    users = User.objects.all()
    if skip_user:
        users = users.exclude(pk=skip_user.id)
    for user in users:
        measurements = Measurement.objects.filter(user=user.id)
        tags = set()
        for measurement in measurements:
            results = MeasurementResult.objects.filter(measurement=measurement)
            for result in results:
                tags.add(result.tag)
        user.tags = ','.join(list(tags))
    return users
```

But I do not like that I am requesting the measurements for each user, and the results for each measurement. Is there a way of getting all this in a single database access?

Besides, I do not like having that `user.tags` ad-hoc property added like this. Is there a better way of doing this? `UserManager` maybe, but how to access related models in a [Model Manager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/managers/)?

What all boils down to is that, even though the values returned by `get_users_with_tags` are perfectly usable by the django template above, those same results are not usable (*not serializable*, because they are not really a `QuerySet`?) for a django rest API.

I would like to improve that function so that it produces results which are usable by both the django templates and by the django rest API framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think for both the scenarios you can use property decorator;

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
born = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
.....

@property
def age(self):
    '''Returns the age of this user'''
    if not self.born:
        return None
    today = date.today()
    return today.year - born.year - ((today.month, today.day) < (born.month, born.day))


@property
def tags(self):
    '''Returns the tags of this user'''
    return MeasurementResult.objects.filter(measurement_id__in=self.measurements.all().values_list('id', flat=True)).distinct().values_list('tag', flat=True)
```

Here you will get a list of tags

Comment: Doesn't even need to be a property, since the django template tag will recognise the method with the OP's current template code

Comment: Indeed; anyway here is a link for the property decorator: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property

Comment: @Sayse, I am confused: do I need to declare it as property for it work in any context? I mean, not only in template context, but also in serializers context.

Comment: @jeckyll2hide - since you can't use `()` in django template language you can still access methods without them. if you wanted to use it in python code you just call it as a method (`.age()`), although can I suggest if you do make it a method that you give it a better name such as `get_age()`

Comment: @Sayse: and if I make it a property, can I access it from django templates normally, like I would access any object attribute? I could keep `age` as the name of the property (since it would not be a method, but a property, the noun name makes more sense). It seems to me that making it a propery makes it more flexible and gives a uniform interface all around the code: in django templates and in other python modules

Comment: @jeckyll2hide - Guess thats just a matter of opinion, I wouldn't really call it a property since it is just doing a calculation

Comment: @Sayse: or, asked another way: is there any drawback (apart from personal preference) to using a property? Things that can not be done if I use a property like, for example, serializing a model?

Comment: @jeckyll2hide you can directly use as a field in serializer, if you are writing as a property

Comment: @GeoJacob: thanks, but your tags implementation have two problems for me: first, it creates a circular dependency User <-> MeasurementResult <-> Measurement <-> User. And second, the implementation is wrong, because it is not the MeasurementResult which is related to an user, but the Measurement. The MeasurementResult is related to a Measurement, so two levels of indirection are neded, and I do not know how to do that ...

Comment: Ohh, yes, I have updated the answer, i think this will work, but not tried.

Comment: Great! Still circular dependency, but the query works like a charm!

Comment: Do imports inside function, it will solve circular dependency.